# How to parse the values from backend and post them at frontend

Tags: joomla-2.5, development, module

I want to make a small edit in an existing module. That module parses articles from the given categories and post them at index. I wanted to add another element (ID) so the user could give the id from an article that isn't in a category and post that Also.

I'm completely new to module development and even the easiest task seems really complex for me right now. So I created the text field at my XML manifest file, and I can add a value and here comes my question/s.

If I'm not mistaken the list type fields are getting saved somewhere in the db and you can retrieve them calling as a list that has default elements.

```
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);
$modell->setState('list.start');
```

It maybe sounds dumb but I didn't find anything about text fields. Or maybe I didn't understand it. So I would like someone to enlighten me on how we generally retrieve the  values user gives at backend so we can echo em at frontend.

And also if someone could recommend me a book or something that could help me with Joomla module development (I tried Joomla Development A beginners Guide by Hagen Graf and Learning Joomla 3 Extension Development 3rd Edition, but they didn't help me a lot as you can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick gave you the right direction - [Adding form fields](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_Form_Fields) is exactly what you need. May be you missed some points from this doc:

- Form fields and parameters can be found on [this page](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types) ([text](http://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type) is also there)
- The form field parameters are stored for each module in the `#__modules` table under the `params` field as JSON encoded string
- You can retrieve the parameter via `$params` variable (it's a [Registry](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Registry.Registry.html) object). For example: `$myParam = $params->get('my_param', '1')` where `my_param` is the name of the field in your manifest file and `'1'` is the default value.
- You can pass the `$params` to modules helper and use it there
- The examples of `$params` usage can be found in any Joomla standard module

Comment: Seems i really misunderstood what i readed , thanks for making it clear ;)

Comment: I forgot the book :) [Joomla! Programming](http://joomlaprogrammingbook.com/) is the one that you should consider to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below links for module development.

[Developing a Basic Module](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module)

[Using Database](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database)

[Adding form fields](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_Form_Fields)

Comment: i allready readed that. I know how the MCV model works i just wanted to know the mechanic i parse from backend,edit,post to frontend.